# How to use ulong's with the PostgreSQL Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

I know that Postgre doesn't support unsigned variables, but in my application, I use a package which constantly uses ulong's, even though the values never go over a the max of a long.

Instead of just casting everywhere I use the data from my db from longs to ulongs, would there be a way to allow my model to use a ulong, but to have it cast to a long before it goes to the db? I have tried: `[DataType("BIGINT")]` over the property in the model, but it still was giving me errors.

This is what my model looks like:

```
[Table("users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("userid")]
    [DataType("BIGINT")]
    public ulong UserId { get; set; }
    [Column("cash")]
    public double Cash { get; set; } = 0.0;
    [Column("messagecooldown")]
    public NpgsqlTimeSpan MessageCooldown { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

}
```